# how to find elements from a list that are not present in another list in r

Tags: r

I have two lists that have the same vectors but with different length

```
list1 <- list(a = 1:10, b = 3:20)
list2 <- list(a = c(2,5,8), b = c(3,5,11,20))
```

I would like to find elements from each vector in `list1` that are not present in the corresponding vector in `list2`. There are similar questions answered for other scripts instead of R.

I expect the final list is

```
lst <- list(a=c(1,3,4,6,7,9,10),b=c(4,6:10,12:19))
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use

```
mapply(setdiff,list1,list2)
#$a
#[1]  1  3  4  6  7  9 10

#$b
#[1]  4  6  7  8  9 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Comment: I was only going to ask in addition whether we can assume that `list1` and `list2` are always "in alignment", with the same number of named elements in the same order. If not, it gets more complicated.

Comment: Good point, I didn't quite catch that, or at least it wasn't as clear when I initially read it.